# How to connect Qt signals and slots using QT Designer and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Designer for the design of my application which contains a "Load File" `QPushButton` (which has been promoted to a custom `loadfile.h`) as well as an QOpenGLWidget (which has been promoted to a custom `OGLWidget.h`).

I wanted to have it so that when I click my "Load File" button it sends a signal to a slot in my `OGLWidget` class which brings up a dialogue and loads the file.

I started by going into signal/slot edit mode in Qt Designer and connected the button to the `openglwidget` with `clicked()` as the signal and a newly added (from within Qt Designer) `populate_mesh_from_obj()`.

I then made a function:

```
void OGLWidget::populate_mesh_from_obj()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

as a test and in the header put:

```
public slots:
   void populate_mesh_from_obj();
```

Now in my head I thought:

1. The signal `clicked()` is already implemented by Qt magic
2. The slot has been implemented by me
3. Qt Designer has connected them somewhere

So to me this should have worked. Any ideas why it hasn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to connect them manually..

```
connect(ui->button, &QPushButton::clicked, yourGlPointer, &OGLWidget::populate_mesh_from_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the accepted answer is incorrect (It's not that it doesn't work manually, but you don't **have to** do it that way).

In fact, QT will automatically connect the signal to all slots that follow a [standard naming convention](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect).

This naming convention for slots goes like this:

```cpp
void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
```

In your case, this means if you created the `QPushButton` in QT Designer like this:

[image: QPushButton Load File]

the `object name` is `loadfile` and the signal name is `clicked`.

Now, declare your function like this in the header:

```cpp
public slots:
   void on_loadfile_clicked();
```

and define it like this in the cpp:

```cpp
void OGLWidget::on_loadfile_clicked()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

and the connection will be automatically taken care of.

This auto-connection feature is actually implemented through the QT Meta-Object compiler. You can retrace what happens by opening the `ui_<classname>.h` file generated by QT Designer. It will contain a function `void setupUi(<QClassName> *<YourClassName>)` containing a line `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(<YourClassName>);`. This is what instructs QTs Meta-Object Compiler to implement the connections for you.